# Functional C# and tail recursion

Tags: c#, functional-programming, iterator

I have the following code:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> cons<T>(T y, IEnumerable<T> xs)
{
    yield return y;
    foreach (var x in xs) yield return x;
}

public static bool empty<T>(IEnumerable<T> xs)
{
    return !xs.GetEnumerator().MoveNext();
}

public static T head<T>(IEnumerable<T> xs)
{
    Debug.Assert(!empty(xs), "Prelude.head: empty list");
    var e = xs.GetEnumerator(); e.MoveNext();
    return e.Current;
}

// repeat x is an infinite list, with x the value of every element
public static IEnumerable<T> repeat<T>(T x)
{
    return cons(x, repeat(x));
}
```

Why does `head(repeat(2))` not work, but if I replace the implementation of `repeat` with:

```
// repeat x is an infinite list, with x the value of every element
public static IEnumerable<T> repeat<T>(T x)
{
    for(;;) yield return x;
}
```

it works?

Comment: Please define "not work".  Are you getting an error?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working" exactly?

Comment: When I run it in a unit test, the test says "Error". I'm new to C# and not really sure how to get more information. =/

Comment: Do you know *which type* of error you get? I'm leaning towards a stack overflow personally. Hint: `return cons(x, repeat(x));` will evaluate `repeat(x)` immediately, not lazily, and since every call to repeat ends up calling itself, you should get a stack overflow exception.

Comment: Also, which unit test framework are you using? If it doesn't report the actual exception thrown you should reconsider that choice for future projects.

Comment: "The agent process was stopped while the test was running."

Comment: wait a second, since when does C# do tail recursion? you need to look at what is generated by the second example and i suspect it's a trampolining call(not simple recursion)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first implementation is not tail recursive.  The last thing to execute would be the `cons()` call, but in order to execute that, it must evaluate `repeat(2)`.  To do that, it must (once again) evaluate `repeat(2)`.  And so on until the stack overflows.

Your second implementation creates an enumerator that returns x indefinitely every time it is asked for the next element.  No re-entrancy, so no stack overflow.

Answer (score 2):

From the looks of it, your first example never terminates so it simply blows the stack. Your second example is implemented as a state-machine which avoids a stack overflow.

Comment: Doesn't `cons` also implement that state machine? Why would the second parameter be eagerly evaluated? In other words, why wouldn't it yield immediately after pulling the first element?

Comment: @Clark - Each stack frame includes a state-machine. There is a huge difference there.

Comment: @Clark: Because C# is not a lazy language. The evaluation order is the same as if the return value was an `int`. `IEnumerable<T>` doesn't magically make it lazy.

Comment: Okay. I get it now. Thank you. I'll upvote both answers, but give the acceptance to the other guy since he has less points right now. =)

Comment: @Clark - Fine by me. Jonathon's answer is written better anyway.

Comment: Thanks!  :)   By the way, if you are interested in lazy evaluation in C#, .NET 4.0 introduced a new class to try to facilitate it in non-lazy evaluated languages like C#.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx for more information.